# Unit tests for event emitter

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

After going through similar topics, still don't know what's wrong with my unit test. Running causes error as in the title.

test setup:

mocked service provided by value

```
export class MockedDrawingService {
  public drawing = {} as Drawing;

  constructor() {}

  add(_server: Server, _project_id:string, _x: number, _y:number, _svg: string) {
    return of(this.drawing);
  }

}
```

in test:

```
it('should add selected drawing', () => {
  //some code here
  spyOn(drawingService, 'add');

  component.addDrawing("rectangle");
  dummyElement.click();

  expect(drawingService.add).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

});

in component:

```
this.drawingService
    .add(this.server, this.project.project_id, x, y, svg)
    .subscribe((serverDrawing: Drawing) => {
      this.drawingsDataSource.add(serverDrawing);
    });
```

line with subscribe causes exception: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined